# Android Hello World Project Error: "Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #2"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

2018/09/27

I upgraded android studio to 3.2.0 and created the default project.
But the compiler shows the error：

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\DELL-BODETY\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_background.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\DELL-BODETY\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\1135036532c8b3c53c96f89a2a22aaca\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\DELL-BODETY\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\DELL-BODETY\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_background.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #1
```

And I can't think of any way out.Just for help！！

Comment: Can you post the contents of \app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_background.xml? It looks like it's not well formed (missing some xml closing tags etc).

Comment: Sorry = =! It's too long to paste,but I guarantee that it is generated by android studio automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> `app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_background.xml`:1: **error: not
>   well-formed (invalid token)**.

Go to `drawable` directory and find this file: `ic_launcher_background.xml`.

It seems like there is a compilation error, spelling mistake, not well typed or etc. You need to check which one is. It should show an error or something with red line error. Probably, used semicolon or something similar.

Comment: I tried to delete the file`ic_launcher_background.xml`,but it shows the new error:`ic_launcher.xml`,then I deleted  the file`ic_launcher.xml`,however,error:`activity_main.xml` showed up.

Comment: Well yeah, ic_launcher should have .png format. I'm guessing that you're using the Icon launcher in the wrong path and with the wrong format. They must be in `mipmap` directory tho. Use `ImageAsset` from right-click on the project for adding launcher icons.

Comment: It seems that all files end in`.xml` are judged as error.

Comment: Well, then I guess there is an implementation mistake-error with those. However, we need to see some codes to check and give you the right answer.